# ComponentWillReceiveProps in ReactNative is not working as expected?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
{ false && <QuestionerDetail questionerId={details.questionerId} /> }
```

I have two questions here

> 1, why is componentWillReceiveProps is called in QuestionerDetail
>   component?
>
> 2, why this.props in QuestionerDetail is an empty object, {}. I just
>   passed questionerId as a prop to it.

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Nobody but you knows what QuestionerDetail is. What does 'working as expected' mean?

Comment: It can be any component that have componentWillRecieveProps life cycle in it.

Comment: @estus QuestionerDetail component is actually not rendered but why does its lifecycle methods execute.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense without MCVE. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. componentWillReceiveProps won't be triggered on first render. If that's the case, componentWillReceiveProps should be avoided, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: Why is componentWillReceiveProps called?**

`componentWillReceiveProps` is called when the component's props change - i.e. whenever it gets initialised with props. This includes the very first time it's initialised.

**Question 2: Why is this.props empty?**

`this.props` isn't set yet when `componentWillReceiveProps` is called - it only **will** receive props. But you can access the imminent props because `componentWillReceiveProps` receives a `nextProps` paramenter.

Note however that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and will disappear in React 17, [here's how you replace it](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607).